# Select with condition from a datatable in VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, datatable

I want to select a certain field from a datatable in VB based on the value of another field in the same row.

In SQL, it would easily be done by writing this query:

```
select error_message from table_errors where error_case="condition"
```

How do I do this if I have my SQL table filled in a datatable in VB?
How do I select the item("error_message") in the datatable **based on** the item("error_Case") field?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Linq-To-DataSet`:

```
Dim matchingRows As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = 
    From row In table
    Where row.Field(Of String)("error_case") = "condition"
```

If you just want one column (of course that works also in one step):

```
Dim errorMessages As IEnumerable(Of String) = 
    From row In matchingRows 
    Select row.Field(Of String)("error_message")

For Each error In errorMessages 
    Console.WriteLine(error)
Next
```

If you expect it to be just a single row use `First` or `Single`(throws an exception if there is more than one row):

```
Dim error As String = errorMessages.First()
```

Since `First` throws an exception if the sequence is empty you can use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
Dim error As String = errorMessages.FirstOrDefault() ' is null/Nothing in case of an empty sequence
```

All in one line (note that both Linq and `DataTable.Select` needs to use loops):

```
Dim ErrMessage As String = errorTable.AsEnumerable().
    Where(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("Error_Case") = TextCase.Text).
    Select(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("Error_Message")).
    FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to avoid loops. I need this several times in my code and I was looking for the shortest way to do it. Tried this http://urlpaste.com/PlKudP5a but it didn't work.

Comment: @HelpASisterOut: Do you think that `DataTable.Select` does not need loops? Of course it also has to loop all rows, there is no magic inside.

Answer (score 0):

here is a worker version of the rough code

```
    Dim connString As String = "select error_message from table_errors where error_case='condition'"
    Dim conn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connString)
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(connString, conn)
    Dim dTable As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim dAdapter As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    dAdapter.Fill(dTable)
    conn.Close()
    Dim text As String
    Dim dReader As DataTableReader = dTable.CreateDataReader()
    While dReader.Read()
        text = dReader.GetValue(0)
    End While
    dReader.Close()
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid linking it to the database every time. I want to load it once and be able to go through the rows depending on different conditions. Tried this http://urlpaste.com/PlKudP5a but it didn't work.

Comment: use a parameter for the select command, this would make it easier to change the filter value, if this is what you need, or exclude the condition all together from the command text and store the values in the DataTable together with the error_case field, but you will need to loop through it in the reader and set conditions on the error_case column.